# FEM 1D poisson substitution integral issue

Tags: finite-element, integration

I'm trying to solve
$
    \begin{cases}
        -u''=f \\
        u(0)=0 \\
        u(1)= \alpha 
    \end{cases}
$
with FEM using reference elements and local coordinates.

So we have the global matrix $K_{ij}=\int_\Omega N_i'(x) N_j'(x)$.

Computing each local matrix for a 2noded element, I have $K^e(\xi)=\begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & -1/2 \\ -1/2 & 1/2 \end{pmatrix}$

To compute its global equivalent, I use the substitution rule
$
\int_{\phi(a)=-1}^{\phi(b)=1} f(\xi)d\xi = \int_a^b f(\phi(x)) \phi'(x) dx
$
with $\xi=\phi(x)=\frac{2}{h}(x-x_c)$ and $\phi'(x)=\frac{2}{h}$.

So basically I have $K^e=K^g\frac{2}{h}$ so $K^g=K^e\frac{h}{2}$.
Here this result is wrong, and I don't know where I missed up.
I'm supposed to have $K^g=K^e\frac{2}{h}$

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

On $[x_i, x_{i+1}]$, you can write
\begin{equation}
N_i(x) = \frac{x_{i+1}-x}{h} = 1 - \xi = \phi_i(\xi) \quad \mbox{where } \;
\xi = \frac{x-x_i}{h}
\end{equation}
So the derivatives satisfy
\begin{equation}
\frac{dN_i}{dx}(x) = - \frac{1}{h} = \frac{d\phi_i}{d\xi}\left(\xi (x) \right) \frac{d\xi}{dx}(x) = (-1) \left( \frac{1}{h} \right)
\end{equation}
So the integral becomes
\begin{equation}
\int_{x_i}^{x_i+h} N_i'(x) N_i'(x) dx = \int_{x_i}^{x_i+h} \left( - \frac{1}{h} \right) \left( - \frac{1}{h} \right) dx = \frac{1}{h}
\end{equation}
If we use the change of variables, we have
\begin{multline}
\int_{x_i}^{x_i+h} N_i'(x) N_i'(x) dx = \int_{x_i}^{x_i+h} 
\left( \frac{d\phi_i}{d\xi}\left(\xi (x) \right) \frac{d\xi}{dx}(x) \right)^2
dx
=
\int_{0}^{h} 
\left( \frac{d\phi_i}{d\xi}\left( \xi \right) \frac{d\xi}{dx}( \xi ) \right)^2
\left( h d\xi \right)
\\
=
\int_{0}^{1} 
\left[ \left( -1 \right) \left( \frac{1}{h} \right) \right]^2
\left( h d\xi \right)
=
\frac{1}{h}
\end{multline}